# Cannot close connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, autobahn

So, I am not sure if this is the correct approach, but this was working properly before the Authors of Autobahn decided to close the AWS Hot Link (completely understandable).

So, the site I am working on basically allows users to select an internal reference, and have a conversation about it (they need to exchange documents, etc).

Whenever they click on a reference, they get subscribed to the server so they can receive real-time updates from other users, but if they change to a different reference, the first subscription needs to be closed out, and then open a new one.

Here's the JavaScript code that is not working as of this morning (After the AWS close out):

```
if (typeof conn == 'undefined') {
      console.log("Conn is undefined...");
    } else {
      conn.close(); // Cerramos la conexión que ya existía, para evitar duplicar conexiones.
    }

    //conn = new ab.Session('wss://plt.prolog-mex.com/wss2/',
    conn = new autobahn.Session('wss://plt.prolog-mex.com/wss2/',

        function() {
            conn.subscribe(idReferencia, function(topic, data) {
                boardUser = $('#messageBoard').attr('usuario');
                if (boardUser == data.idUsuario) {
                  clase = 'message-own';
                } else {
                  clase = 'message-nonown';
                }

                $('#messageBoard').prepend('<p class="'+ clase +'"><span><b>'+data.usuario+' | '+data.when+'</b></span><br>'+data.article+'</p>')

            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
```

I'm thinking that the version I got from GitHub is not the same version they had on AWS, but that's just an assumption.

Any ideas?

Comment: The version at https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js-built is identical to what was published on AWS as autobahn-latest. From the looks of your connection function, you are using a really old version however. Check https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/issues/270#issuecomment-288945207 to see if this leads you to a version that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I am using a really old version. I just came to realize this right now. Ratchet has stoped developing the library and is stuck using WAMPv1 protocol. The guys from autobahn JS actually stopped supporting it since '14 - the main problem is that Legacy versions were gone alongside with the bucket they took out a few days ago (oldest you could get is version 0.9, I am in 0.8)

2 years ago, sergeyvolkov decided to upload the files to GitHub (https://github.com/sergeyvolkov/autobahn-old) and I was able to get the 0.8 version from there and have my site up and running again.

There's the site in case anybody else had their site broken as well, however it is better if you replace Ratchet with Thruway so that you can use the newer versions of WAMP and Autobahn.